# (Android) How to grab EditText value?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an app that is supposed to:
1. If Spinner value is "1", do a certain math equation from EditText value
2. If Spinner value is "2", do a certain math equation from EditText value
I'm getting "NullPointerException"
Here is my code:

```
package org.infinitech.degreescalculator.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    public String selectedItem;
    Integer number;
    Integer a;
    String numberTwo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        final TextView answerText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        final Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.options);
            final String inputTwo=(String)getText(R.id.input);
    selectedItem=(String)spinner.getSelectedItem();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(selectedItem.equals("Fahrenheit to Celsius")){
                    a=Integer.parseInt(inputTwo);
                    number=a*100;
                    numberTwo=number.toString();
                    answerText.setText(numberTwo);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We are here to help when you have a specific question. I suggest that you fire up a debugger to help you narrow down the problem. After debugging, if you still can't figure out how to fix it, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `selectedItem` is assigned in your `onCreate` method, which runs before any of the items in your spinner have been selected, and is therefore always `null`.  Move the line that assigns it to inside your button click listener's `onClick` method, and it should solve the problem.

Similarly, you may also need to move your `inputTwo` variable into the `onClick` method, so this too is not set at creation time and never updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value as a `String` like this:

```
editTextObject.getText().toString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I added my code.  Hopefully you can debug it from there.

Comment: @InfiniTech What's your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am getting "NullPointerException".  I cannot see what would cause that in this code, as there are no warnings or errors.

Comment: @InfiniTech See the link I posted to your question for more help on tracking down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this line `final String inputTwo=(String)getText(R.id.input);` will not give any value so instead doing it like that just directly get the text of it inside the onclick of the button.

**Change this:**

```
a=Integer.parseInt(inputTwo);
```

**to:**

```
a=Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```